# Proving a pseudo prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $p > 3$ is a prime, then $n = \frac{2^p+1}{3}2^{p-1}$ is a pseudoprime (base 2). Hints: Use the facts that for $p > 3$ we have both $2p | n-1$ and $2^{2p} \equiv 1 \mod n$

I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Any number $n=\frac{4^p  - 1}3$, where $p≥5 -$ prime, satisfies the condition.

1) $n=\frac{(2^p  -1)(2^p  +1)}3$ is composed so $\frac{2^p±1}3  >1$ for $p≥5.$

2) As $n - $ odd, then $2|n-1$. In addition, the small Fermat theorem can be proved that $p|n-1$ . Then, $n-1=2pk$, where $k∈ \mathbb N$.

Then $2^{n-1}  -1=(4^p )^k  - 1$, and therefore $$4^p-1|2^{(n-1)}  -1 \Rightarrow n|2^{(n-1)}  -1$$